# mostrar consultas por carreras

Tags: php, sql, pdo

la idea es mostrar las consultas por carrera

en la imagen siguiente: los primeros 4 registros a la derecha son de la segunda carrera y los 4 últimos de la primera carrera y esta mal, ejemplo la consulta de la izquierda me muestra  que es la Segunda Carrera y la consulta de la derecha debe mostrarme solo los 4 primeros registros que son los asociados a la segunda carrera el problema es ese

la relación son las siguientes: `carreras_caballos.id_carreras_caballos=ejemplar.id_carreras_caballos`

anexo la imagen y consultas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<?php
     $sql2 = "SELECT 
                         carreras_caballos.id_carreras_caballos,
                         carreras_caballos.id_carreras,
                         ejemplar.id_ejemplar,
                         ejemplar.id_carreras_caballos,
                         ejemplar.ejemplar,
                         ejemplar.peso,
                         ejemplar.dividendo,
                         ejemplar.porcentaje,
                         ejemplar.total
                         FROM carreras_caballos
              INNER JOIN ejemplar ON carreras_caballos.id_carreras_caballos=ejemplar.id_carreras_caballos        
 ORDER BY carreras_caballos.id_carreras_caballos=ejemplar.id_carreras_caballos AND carreras_caballos.id_carreras = 1
  ";

 $consulta = $DB_con->prepare($sql2);
 $consulta->execute();
 if($consulta->rowCount() > 0){
 $i=1;
 ?>
```

Comment: Añade el `WHERE` para filtrar por carrera y que solo te aparezcan los de la carrera indicada. De todas formas no se entiende muy bien del todo el problema

Comment: osea me explico así me lo muestra bien pero me esta mostrando los demás resultados y solo debería mostrarme los asociados al registro de la izquierda ejemplo los 4 primero registro son los de la tercera carrera y los 4 últimos registros de la derecha son los de la segunda carrera y deberia mostrarme solo los 4 primero registro de la tabla de la derecha que son los asociados a la tercera carrera te anexo la imagen: https://prntscr.com/i54jp6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

listo ya lo pude resolver anexo la solución:

```
 <?php
     $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM ejemplar WHERE id_carreras_caballos = (SELECT MAX(id_carreras_caballos) from ejemplar)";
     $consulta = $DB_con->prepare($sql2);
     $consulta->execute();
     if($consulta->rowCount() > 0){
     $i=1;
?>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

gracias a todos...

Comment: Pero en tu solución no aparece la tabla `carreras_caballos` ¿...?

Comment: esa esta bien el problema era la tabla ejemplar, ah saludo tiempo sin saber de usted amigo espero este bien

Answer (score 0):

No tienes un where en tu consulta, 
ORDER BY carreras_caballos.id_carreras_caballos=ejemplar.id_carreras_caballos AND carreras_caballos.id_carreras = 1
esta parte esta mal en vez de order by deberias tener el where ejemplo
... INNER JOIN ejemplar ON carreras_caballos.id_carreras_caballos=ejemplar.id_carreras_caballos
 WHERE carreras_caballos.id_carreras = 1
y quitar de nuevo carreras_caballos.id_carreras_caballos=ejemplar.id_carreras_caballos ya que esa relacion esta en el inner

Comment: lo puse como me dijiste pero ahora me muestra los 4 registros que es lo que se quiere, pero me los muestra de la primera carrera cuando debería ser de la tercera carrera

Comment: muestra el sql que estas usando y ojo con el id que debes cambiar para que te muestre los datos asociados a la carrera que escoges

Comment: https://prntscr.com/i5537s  y el resultado es el siguiente: https://prntscr.com/i553k2

Comment: la consulta esta bien lo que me faltaria agregar es como el order by en desc

Comment: Veo que tienes quemada carreras_caballos.id_carreras = 1 y ahi deberias pasarle la variable para que cambie si no siempre te va a mostrar lo mismo, toma ese sql y correlo en la gestor que utilices y cambiale el 1 por otro id que tengas en la tabla carreras_caballos para que pilles

Comment: ok y entonces como debería ser para mostrar esa consulta como se requiere

Comment: supongo que tienes una lista de todas las carreras en una pagina y al dar click a una de las carreras te envia a la pagina donde la info de los caballos y no cambia (eso es lo que creo que haces si no es asi coloca la informacion de como lo que estas haciendo), entonces debes enviar una variable con el id de la carrera desde la pagina anterior ya sea por post o get y obtenerla en la pagina donde tienes el sql y concatenar la variable que obtuviste en el sql precisamente donde esta el uno, ejemplo si llamaste a la var $id_carrera deberia quedar carreras_caballos.id_carreras = ". $id_carrera